# Save preferences for an entire workspace in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Using this snippet, a property can be easily stored for a project:

```
((IResource) getElement()).setPersistentProperty(new QualifiedName("", "MY_PROPERTY"), "MY_VALUE");
```

But how can I store preferences that can be accessed in every project in the workspace?

Comment: Have a look at [Eclipse Preferences Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html)

Comment: Following the tutorial there, when I try to get the object instance using this line `Preferences preferences = ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE.getNode("my_plugin");`, `INSTANCE` cannot be resolved, but I'm importing the correct class `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.ConfigurationScope`

Comment: Works fine here. The INSTANCE static field was not in very, very old versions of Eclipse (added in Eclipse 3.4).